# how do i recreate this msdos extended partition layout

Tags: partition

I want to use `parted` on a new disk to create this layout.  I saved this info a while ago and now need to recreate on a new disk.  can this be done with `parted` ?

```
Seagate Barracuda  ST500DM002    500GB
cylinder size = 7.84mb
mdos disk label


partition   type                       size           label       cylinders
sdb1        0x83 linux native (ext3)   101.94mb       boot         0..12
sdb2        0x05 extended              14.81gb                    13..1945

sdb5        0x83 linux native (ext3)   3.07gb         root        13..413
sdb6        SWAP                       196.08mb       swap00      414..438
sdb7        0x83 linux native (ext3)   290.21mb       mm          439..475
sdb8        0x83 linux native (ext3)   101.94mb       config      476..488
sdb9        0x83 linux native (ext3)   3.73gb         data        489..975
sdb10       0x83 linux native (ext3)   3.73gb         work        976..1462
sdb11       0x83 linux native (ext3)   290.21mb       ss          1463..1499
sdb12       0x83 linux native (ext3)   290.21mb       ss-rw       1500..1536
sdb13       0x83 linux native (none)   3.13gb                     1537..1945
```

why would sdb3 and sdb4 be missing?

Comment: sdb5 is there.....I don't understand the final comment.

Comment: I think OP means the gap sdb3 sdb4

Comment: sorry, typo, i corrected; why no sdb3 and no sdb4 listed?

Comment: To recreate the exact layout you'll need a bit more info: the LBAs for beginnings of each partition, as well as (exact) sizes of the partitions. Otherwise, answer by davolfman is the way to go.

Comment: i had tar'd all the data from each partition, nothing was more than 20% full.  I hope to untar accordingly... the partition sizes can change but I need to preserve the labels and i think the dev/sd# so that the system boots on any new disk

Comment: it's fundamentally linux but modified by the manufacturer to operate their hardware.

Comment: You should doublecheck /etc/fstab and make sure the partitions are actually referenced by /dev/sd* device nodes.  If they're reached by UUID your life is going to be drastically more complicated.

Comment: good point.  it was all `by-label`

Answer (score 3):

This partition layout uses extended partitions.
The boot partition at sdb1 is a primary partition, it's information is on the master boot record.  Unfortunately the master boot record only has 4 slots for partitions, so to get this many partitions a system of logical partitions on sdb2 with the remaining space on disk (I'm assuming) is used.

At the beginning of sdb2 is a new partition table containing the information on it's partition (sdb5) and another entry on where to find the next logical partition (sdb6).  The logical partitions proceed like this in a linked-list fashion each one with the information on itself and how to find the next, divvying up the space of sdb2 into many smaller partitions. By convention the primary paritions are sdX1-sdX4 and logical/extended partitions start at sdX5. Even if all the primary partitons aren't used the extended partitions will start at sdX5.

To create this layout you would:

Create an MBR partition table:

Create one 101.94mb primary partition

Create logical/extended partitions of size, 3.07gb, 196.08mb, 290.21mb, 101.94mb, 3.73gb, 3.73gb, 290.21mb, 290.21mb, and 3.13gb.